# Why the thread suspends?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am trying to understand producer and consumer program but when I create the object thread1 in main function the thread suspends (mainHumpty Dumpty sat on a wall) why is this happened?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message mes = new Message();
        Writer t1 = new Writer(mes);
        t1.start();
        while(true)
        {   
        t1.run();       
        }
    }
}

class Message { 

private String message; 
private boolean empty = true;

public synchronized String read() {
    while(empty) {
     try{
      wait();
       }
     catch(InterruptedException e)
     {
     }
    }
    empty = true;
    notifyAll();
    return message;
}

public synchronized void write(String message) {
    while(!empty) {
    try{
      wait();
       }
   catch(InterruptedException e)
     {
     }
    }
    empty = false;
    notifyAll();
    this.message = message;
}
}

class Writer extends Thread { 

private Message message;
public Writer(Message message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public void run() {
    String messages[] = {
            "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall",
            "Humpty Dumpty had a great fall",
            "All the king's horses and all the king's men",
            "Couldn't put Humpty together again"
    };

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
        message.write(messages[i]);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + messages[i]);
    try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }
    message.write("Finished");`
```

I expected to print infinitely all the members of the array and the name of the thread which I created but the only that is printed is the first string and the main thread

Comment: You don't even need to think about multithreading to break this one down. Think about things step by step. Here's a hint: (1) what is `message.empty` at the end of the first `write` call? And then (2) what happens at the second `write` call, with `message.empty` having that value?

Comment: @yshavit  In the first call `message.empty` is `true` so it  loops  infinitely inside the loop when the code reaches wait the current function releases the lock
 but after this i step  I confused 
When we call wait method which is inside an infinite loop this funtion break the loop and changes the value of empty  and all the code which is above wait is skipped ?

Comment: @up10388 in the first call to `write`, `empty` is `true`, so `while(!empty)` is skipped. Then, it sets `empty` to `false` and sets the message. The problem here is that nothing ever calls `read`, so writes after the first one will block indefinitely. This is just a producer with no consumer.